# List.Contains returns incorrect result but List.Exists works

Tags: c#, linq, com

I have a list of COM objects. When I check whether a given COM object exists in the list, the contains method returns incorrect result sometimes, while exists always works. Any idea why this might be happening?

```
bool CheckContains(List<object> objectList, object target){
     //return objectList.Contains(target); Gives incorrect results sometimes
     return objectList.Exists(obj=>obj==target); //Always works
}
```

Comment: You are using different comparisons (`Equals` for `Contains` and that could be overloaded vs `==` that simply does reference comparison and that can't be overloaded)... And there is no "microsoft" `Exists` for `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: `IEnumerable.Exists` doesn't even exist (no pun intended)

Comment: Corrected to List. The code was demonstrative and hence the mistake.

Comment: I've deleted my answer for the time being - but can you post a compilable reproduction of the problem? I doubt we will get much further without that.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I am dealing with COM objects created by an external application. I am not sure how I can post a compilable reproduction.

Comment: But you said that you "have implemented IEquatable correctly and also overriden GetHashCode() accordingly", so what is the code for that? It must be for the type of objects in the list, yes?

Comment: I have created managed objects which contain these COM objects. Yes, the list is of managed objects for which IEquatable and GetHashCode() have been implemented. These use the hash code of the underlying COM object.

Comment: `GetHashCode` doesn't matter in this case. If the reference equality works ok, then it sounds like an incorrect `Equals` implementation. Check your implementation or post the code.

Answer (score 0):

convert from the non-generic to generic using Cast or OfType try this,

```
bool CheckContains(nonGeneric.Cast(IEnumerable<object>     objectList)).Contains(target){
        return objectList.Contains(target);
   }
```